# GCloud Home Directory Permissions for new users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Is there a way to override the default home directory permissions for new users on a compute engine instance?

I tried to modify `/etc/adduser.conf`, but it does not seem to be used for accounts created automatically when accessing the instance for the first time using the GCloud SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the parameter UMASK in the file /etc/login.defs in order to change the default home directory permission for new users created from the GCloud SDK.

The value of UMASK for default is 022 that means rwx-rw--rw-,you can simply subtract the umask from the base permissions to determine the final permission for directory as follows:
777 – 022 = 755

Directory base permissions : 777
umask value : 022
Subtract to get permissions of new directory (777-022) : 755 (rwxr-xr-x)

The above is an example of value 022 but you can set your UMASK as you need, in this link you can find how to calculate the UMASK value https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html.

Comment: 022 that means rwx-r-xr-x as a mask. I am assuming just a type in your answer. However, this is a bad security practice. This allows everyone to read everyone's files.

Comment: Yes, that was only an example and those are the default permissions for the value UMASK in the file /etc/login.defs so you can set the permission as your needs and set more restrictive permission for the home directory of the new users.